# Parallels Plesk scheduling a task with wget command

Tags: php, iis, cron, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I'm running Parallels Plesk on a Hostgator windows server. I am trying to set up a 'Scheduled Task' ie cron job running every 5 minutes that simply loads a webpage, nothing more. This is my current setup:

[image]

Unfortunately, nothing seems to work. I was ideally looking for something like wget "myurl" to keep it simple, but it doesn't look like it takes commands, only executables. I created a php script with a file_get_contents to load the page, and used the PHP installation as the executable passing the script location as the argument, but this doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong? What I am trying to achieve is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it happens because of spaces in path C:\Program Files (x86)\

Try to quoting full path to PHP binary.